# How to use the same model for adding and editing in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working for Ionic Ecommerce app and I am working on the two functionalities for adding and editing the shipping address.

I have used the modal for adding the shipping the address and I want to use the same modal for editing the shipping address.

This is my **shipping.html**:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons>
      <button style="border: 1px solid;" navPop>
        <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2 class="myformh2">Add Your Shipping Address</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="shippingdet" (ngSubmit)="getShippingDetails()">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="newitem2">
        <ion-input placeholder="Name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="userData.shipping_name" formControlName="shipping_name"
          required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="newitem2">
        <ion-input placeholder="Mobile Number" type="number" [(ngModel)]="userData.shipp_mob" formControlName="shipp_mob"
          required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="newitem2">
        <ion-input placeholder="Country" type="text" value="India" disabled></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="newitem2">
        <ion-select placeholder="Select State" [(ngModel)]="userData.shipp_state" formControlName="shipp_state"
          required (ionChange)="onChange(userData.shipp_state)">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let pstate of this.statesdetails" value="{{pstate.state_id}}">{{pstate.state_name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="newitem2">
        <ion-select placeholder="Select City" [(ngModel)]="userData.shipp_city" formControlName="shipp_city" required>
          <ion-option *ngFor="let pcity of this.citiesdetails" value="{{pcity.city_id}}">{{pcity.city_name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="newitem2">
        <ion-input placeholder="Pincode" type="number" [(ngModel)]="userData.shipp_code" formControlName="shipp_code"
          required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="newitem2">
        <textarea placeholder="Address" [(ngModel)]="userData.shipping_address" formControlName="shipping_address"
          required></textarea>
      </ion-item>
      <div>
        <button [disabled]="!shippingdet.valid" ion-button type="submit" class="newbtn11" color="primary" block>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

This is my modal that I have used for the adding the shipping address and I want to use the same modal for the editing the shipping address.

When the user clicks for editing, it should show, **Edit Your Shipping Address** in place of **Add Your Shipping Address** and also the button text should update like Update and the function also.

This is my **shipping.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { RestapiProvider } from '../../providers/restapi/restapi';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-shipping',
  templateUrl: 'shipping.html',
})
export class ShippingPage {
  shippingdet : FormGroup;
  userData = {"shipping_name": "", "shipp_mob": "", "shipp_code": "", "shipp_state": "", "shipp_city": "", "shipping_address": "",};
  states: any = [];
  statesdetails: any = [];
  cities: any = [];
  citiesdetails: any = [];
  responseData2: any;
  editdeta: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public restProvider: RestapiProvider,
    private storage: Storage) {
      this.shippingdet = this.formBuilder.group({
        shipping_name: ['', Validators.required],
        shipp_mob: ['', Validators.required],
        shipp_code: ['', Validators.required],
        shipp_state: ['', Validators.required],
        shipp_city: ['', Validators.required],
        shipping_address: ['', Validators.required],
      });

      if(navParams.get('itm'))
      {
        console.log(navParams.get('itm'));
        this.editdeta = navParams.get('itm');
        this.editshippingUser();
      }
      this.getAllStates();
  }
  getShippingDetails()
  {
    this.storage.get("ID").then((val) =>
    {
      if(val)
      {
       this.addShippingUsers(val);
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("Please Login");
      }
    });
    this.closeModal();
  }

  getAllStates()
  {
    this.restProvider.getstates()
      .then(data => {
      this.states = data;
      this.statesdetails = this.states.msg.states;
      });
  }

  onChange(selectedstate){
    this.getAllCities(selectedstate);
  }

  getAllCities($cid)
  {
    this.restProvider.getcities($cid)
      .then(data => {
      this.cities = data;
      this.citiesdetails = this.cities.msg.city;
      });
  }

  addShippingUsers($usid)
  {
    this.shippingdet.controls;
    this.restProvider.addshipping(this.userData, 'delivery_address/'+$usid).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.responseData2 = data;
      }
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ShippingPage');
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }

  editshippingUser()
  {
    this.userData.shipping_name = this.editdeta.name;
    this.userData.shipp_mob = this.editdeta.mobile;
    this.userData.shipp_code = this.editdeta.pincode;
    this.userData.shipp_state = this.editdeta.state_id;
    this.userData.shipp_city = this.editdeta.city_id;
    this.userData.shipping_address = this.editdeta.address;
  }
}
```

In this ts file, I am getting this parameter for the update `if(navParams.get('itm'))` and when this parameter exists, I should update the text in the modal and the function also.

This is my modal for adding the shipping address and I am using the same model for editing the shipping address but the problem is that I am not able to show the Edit Your Shipping address and Update the button text and also update the function in the form.

> (ngSubmit)="getShippingDetails()"

This is for adding the shipping address and I want to replace this function when editing the form.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: have you tried setting the string from the ts file based on whether you have `editdeta` or not?

Comment: @SurajRao. No I have tried that and what about the function that I have to run depending on the edit or add modal.

Comment: @SurajRao. Can you please help me?

Comment: its an if else condition based on editdeta..

Comment: @SurajRao. Okay but what for the function (ngSubmit)="getShippingDetails()". Can I also use the if else for that.

Comment: @SurajRao. Can I use *ngIf for the heading text?

Comment: Yes... Thats angular. try it..

Comment: Also.. a suggestion: stick to either reactive or template based form. Avoid mixing them both

Comment: @SurajRao. Okay, I got it and thank you for your suggestion. It helped me solving my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add condition from where you are opening this shipping model, i have added both case in below code

1)Add shipping

> var modalPage = this.modalCtrl.create(ShippingPage, {type:"add" });
>           modalPage.present();

2)Edit shipping details

> var modalPage = this.modalCtrl.create(ShippingPage, {type:"edit" });
>           modalPage.present();

And from shipping page you just need to get navParams value and perform operation according to that
For example

> var operationType=navParams.get('type')

In operationType you will get which operation you need to perform

Comment: I have also pasted my answer.

Comment: Welcome, let me know if you have still issue.

Comment: No, Thank you for your answer. I have solved my query.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

**For the heading**:

```
<h2 class="myformh2">{{(editMode ? 'Edit Your Shipping Address' : 'Add Your Shipping Address')}}</h2>
```

**For the button:**

```
<button [disabled]="!shippingdet.valid" ion-button type="submit" class="newbtn11" color="primary" block>{{(editMode ? 'Edit' : 'Submit')}}</button>
```

**And For the Function:**

```
<form [formGroup]="shippingdet" (ngSubmit)="editMode ? editShippingDetails() : getShippingDetails()">
```

**In the ts file:**

```
editMode: boolean = false;
if(navParams.get('itm'))
    {
        console.log(navParams.get('itm'));
        this.editMode = true;
    }
```